# Ways to avoid CakePHP $this->data security hole?

Tags: database, security, model, cakephp-1.3

I just realized when doing basic CakePHP stuff, that there is quite bad security issue, which many don't necessarily notice. I'll just take this basic function that I think many users use while doing CakePHP driven apps.

```
function edit() {
  if(!empty($this->data)) {
    if($this->User->save($this->data)) {
    }
  }
}
```

Lets assume user has privileges to use this action. This action could be editing user information, which may have like city and number and ofcourse username. Lets assume that we want to have a form that allows us to edit just the city and number but not the username. Well what if someone just inserts that username field into that form with firebug for example? Then submits the form. Now the edit would just grab all the post information, including the username field and its value and edit them straight away. So you can change your username in this case even though there werent a field for it.

This can go even further, if someone would use saveAll(), which allows you to validate and save multiple models in one shot. If you could guess from form fields the models to use, you could easily go to other models and tables aswell and alter those information.

Now that you understand my concerns, my question is what would be the best or atleast near the best method to avoid this?

I know I could just grab the data I want from $this->data to other variable and then pass that to the save or saveAll, but because there are many forms and ajax requests, that would be quite a lot of work. But is it the only way to go or are there better ways?

Should I make or is there a behavior which could stop this? Like checking what variables some action in some controller can get from post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of days research I found that this is not really a "security hole", but rather beginners mistake.

There are two ways avoiding this type of form tampering: Security component ( http://book.cakephp.org/view/1296/Security-Component ) which automatically gets CSRF and form tampering protection by creating one-time hashes for form fields.

The other way is to give the third parameter to save() function. The save actually gets 3 parameters: data, validate, fieldlist. The fieldlist parameter acts like whitelist of fields that are allowed to be saved.

I first reported this problem as a bug to cakephp which it then wasn't but this euromark guy replied to me that he had done nice documenting about the actual problem and how to do secure saves and I really think it was quite good reading. So if you have the same problems, please see this page: http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/